# mysql запрос в Laravel (без ORM)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
 Здравствуйте ребята, как писать сырой запрос mysql в laravel?

 вот это запрос (он рабочий, только в mysql >= 5.6 а у меня на сервере 
 старый 5.5 )
 DB::table('categories')
        ->leftJoin('data', 'categories.id', '=', 'data.categories_id')
        ->select('categories.*',  DB::raw("count(data.categories_id) as 
 video_count"))
        ->groupBy('categories.id')
        ->get();

 нужно писать так
 DB::select("SELECT * FROM ....");
```

Comment: я сам нашел ответ))
DB::select("SELECT COUNT(`data`.categories_id) AS data_count, categories.*  
FROM categories LEFT JOIN `data` ON (`data`.categories_id = categories.id) 
GROUP BY categories.id");

Answer (score 0):

Вот нашел в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries)

```
$users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);
```

Comment: документацию я читал, конкретно нужно было писать сам запрос